# Am I loading this xml file right?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using C# to load an XML file but I don't think I'm doing it in the best way possible, I would really appreciate it if someone either verified the way I'm doing it is an acceptable way or point me in the right direction to do it a better way.

I'm only posting a portion of what I do to load the XML file, but I use this technique for everything,

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmldir);
var layers = doc.Document.Descendants("Layer");
foreach (var layer in layers)
{
    if (layer.Attribute("Name").Value == "Terrain")
    {
        LoadTerrain(layer);
    }
}

// The load terrain function:
public void LoadTerrain(XElement elements)
{
    var items = elements.Descendants("Items");
    var element = elements.Descendants("CustomProperties").Descendants("Property");

    float tileSize = 0;
    string tileTexture = "";
    foreach (var property in element)
    {
        if (property.Attribute("Name") != null)
        {
            string name = property.Attribute("Name").Value;
            if (name == "TileSize")
            {
                tileSize = float.Parse(property.Attribute("Description").Value);
            }
            else if (name == "Texture")
            {
                tileTexture = property.Attribute("Description").Value;
            }
        }
    }

    PhysicShape shape = new PhysicShape(world, JabActor.BodyType.STATIC);
    shape.TextureDir = tileTexture;
    shape.TileSize = tileSize;
    shape.Initialize();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var parts = item.Descendants("Item");

        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            if (part.Name == "Item")
            {
                element = part.Descendants("Position");
                float posx = float.Parse(element.Elements("X").ElementAt(0).Value);
                float posy = float.Parse(element.Elements("Y").ElementAt(0).Value);

                ////element = part.Descendants("Rotation");
                float rot = float.Parse(part.Elements("Rotation").ElementAt(0).Value);

                element = part.Descendants("Scale");
                float width = float.Parse(element.Elements("X").ElementAt(0).Value);
                float height = float.Parse(element.Elements("Y").ElementAt(0).Value);


                shape.AddRectangle(new Vector3(posx, -posy, 0), new Vector2(width, height), rot);
            }
        }
    }

    shape.FinalizeVertices();
    AddNode(shape);
}
```

Here's the XML file: http://medsgames.com/levelg.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not bad, but the best way to do it is XML serialization. You create an XSD schema, from that you can create C# code with the xsd.exe SDK tool, and then you can read or write XML with ~3 lines of code. There's tons of information about this on the web.

Answer (score 2):

If it works, and performs as you need it, I'd say it's right. You *could* implement IXmlSerializable for your objects and take advantage of some useful serialization/deserialization framework code instead of parsing xml yourself.

Either create the schema first and generate the class with xsd.exe, or look up [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can try deserializing XML into C# objects. Try this excellent post:
  [Deserialize XML](http://savagelook.com/blog/portfolio/quick-tip-deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c)